# Simple regex advice needed

Tags: php, regex

Unfortunately, due to bad planning I need to edit a huge html form, field by field. But since it's just find&replace I think I can make the process faster.
So... all the fields looks more or less like this:

```
<td align="left" width="30%">Incoming date:</td>
<td align="left">
<input name="inc_date" class="frmfixededit" size="20"></td>
</tr>
....
<td align="left" width="30%">Name:</td>
<td align="left">
<input name="name" class="frmfixededit" size="20"></td>
</tr>
```

What I want to do is change that to this:

```
<td align="left" width="30%">Incoming date:</td>
<td align="left">
<input name="inc_date" <?php if ($u==TRUE) echo "value='$row['inc_date']'"; ?> class="frmfixededit" size="20"></td>
</tr>
....
<td align="left" width="30%">Name:</td>
<td align="left">
<input name="name" <?php if ($u==TRUE) echo "value='$row['name']'"; ?> class="frmfixededit" size="20"></td>
</tr>
```

Any advice on how i can accomplish that? I don't know how to match that

Thanks

Comment: use find/replace all in your ide , or notepad++ :>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your IDE of choice perform a Regex Find & Replace with find pattern:

```
<input name="(.*)" class="(.*)" size="20">
```

and replace pattern:

```
<input name="$1" <?php if ($u==TRUE) echo "value='$row['$1']'"; ?> class="$2" size="20">
```

Just worked for me in Textmate.

Comment: I'm using aptana and the replace fails. But I will download texmate.

Comment: I tried that on notepad++ and it works. Thanks a lot! Saved me a lot of time and work :)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$result = preg_replace(
    '/<input name="  # Match start of tag
    ([^"]+)        # Match and capture the name
    "              # Match closing quote
    (.*)           # Match and capture rest of the line/x', 
    '<input name="\1" <?php if ($u==TRUE) echo "value=\'$row[\'\1\']\'"; ?>\2', $subject);
```